# Building OBS Studio Music Edition on windows CMake 'Configure' error

Tags: windows, cmake, asio, obs

I'm having a problem building obs music edition on windows, running "Configure" on cmake-gui.

I got this error

```
CMake Warning (dev) at plugins/win-asio/CMakeLists.txt:38 (target_link_libraries):
  Link library type specifier "optimized" is followed by specifier "debug"
  instead of a library name.  The first specifier will be ignored.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at plugins/win-asio/CMakeLists.txt:38 (target_link_libraries):
  The "debug" argument must be followed by a library.


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I attach an image with my current config:
[image: Cmake configuration]

Anyone has any idea what might be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The erroneous `target_link_libraries` call [dereferences](https://github.com/pkviet/obs-studio/blob/master/plugins/win-asio/CMakeLists.txt#L38) variable `JUCE_LIB`, which is previously set as `set(JUCE_LIB optimized ${JUCE_LIBRARY} debug ${JUCE_LIBRARY_DEBUG})`. But variables `JUCE_LIBRARY` and `JUCE_LIBRARY_DEBUG` seem to be never defined. Report the problem to the developers.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, opened issue https://github.com/pkviet/obs-studio/issues/52 as suggested. Thanks